# When would one install a Guice module?

Tags: java, guice

I'm referring to [Binder.install()](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/inject/Binder.html#install%28com.google.inject.Module%29) - when would one use that?

Comment: There's no such method - the `Module` interface has only one method, and it's called `configure`. Do you mean the method you linked to, `Binder.install(Module)` ?

Answer (score 12):

A couple examples:

- Your module depends on bindings from another module and you don't expect the user of your module to provide those bindings (they're for some internal stuff, perhaps).
- You'd prefer to group several modules in one rather than listing them all out in `Guice.createInjector`. For example, you might want to install several modules for services inside the `ServletModule` that defines the servlets/filters that use those services.